# Showing content from another server on a domain without changing URL

Tags: .htaccess, multiple-domains

I have seen a few similar questions on here, but none of the answers have seemed to get me where I need to be.

I have a site, say:

www.first.com

And another site called:

www.second.com

The second.com domain is on a different server than first.com, but they are for the same company. I am trying to merge the domains into www.first.com so that end users only see first.com for this particular brand.

There is a Java applet running on www.second.com/applet that needs to stay on its own server. However, I would like to only have one domain to access the contents on both www.first.com and www.second.com -- I have looked into a 301 redirect, but I am trying to only have ONE SINGLE domain for this. The problem with a 301 is that the URL changes and displays "www.second.com" in the domain, which is what I am trying to avoid.

I would like to have JUST www.first.com and if someone goes to "www.first.com/applet" it shows the content from "www.second.com/applet" but KEEP "www.first.com/applet" in the URL bar, but this is seemingly difficult to achieve with my level of knowledge.

I have tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?first\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.second.com/$1 [P]
```

to no avail. I get the following error:

Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.
X-Forwarded-Server
/n
Apache Server at * Port 80

---

I have read a little about a reverse proxy or something that may work.

How would I properly configure this? I found this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://example.com
  ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com
  ServerName sub.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

From here: [How to show content from other domain without changing the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573844/how-to-show-content-from-other-domain-without-changing-the-url)

But I am not trying to use a subdomain. Hopefully I have explained what I need here. Basically, merging two domains that need to remain on separate servers but be delivered from a single domain.

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

It is very easy:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^Domainyoustayat.tld
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://Domain-you-want-to-show-on-above.tld/$1 [P]
```