# Is it possible to have main site serving content from microsite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have 2 website in 2 different servers,

- `http://www.example.com` is the mainsite (dotnet)
- `http://help.example.com` is a microsite (wordpress)

  ```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
  RewriteRule ^/help(.*)$ http://help.faceoff.com/ [L]
  ```

With the above configuration, when user go to `http://www.example.com/help` it will redirect to the `http://help.example.com/`.

Is it possible to have the `http://www.example.com/help` in the URL bar, but serving content from `http://help.example.com/`?

Comment: You will need to proxy the request, either using the mod_rewrite `P` flag, https://stackoverflow.com/q/29618591/1427878, or via mod_proxy, https://stackoverflow.com/q/26573844/1427878

Comment: That means you need to have the proxy module loaded into your apache http server.

Comment: It's stated that the "mainsite" (where the _reverse proxy_ would need to be implemented) uses "dotnet", so it would seem unlikely to be Apache?